# How do I play aim_botz map?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

My question is, how do I play the aim_botz map? I saw how Scream played this map, but I don't know how I can play it. I was looking at the servers, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You should seperate the question and the answer! Right now, your answer is in the question location. Edit that, and it can be useful.

Comment: Is it better now ? I want to help people who have question : How to play or how to get this map...

Comment: I meant that you can answer your own question, below (under, "Your answer"). So basically everything from "I found solution" should go there. In that way, you seperated the question and the answer, and that is exactly something we like to have here. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Okay, I moved this solution to answers ;)

Comment: Very good. You see, the upvotes are rolling in :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Navigate to this [Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=243702660) page:
2. Subscribe to the map.
3. Restart Steam and start CS:GO.
4. Open the Console, write `map aim_botz` and press Enter
5. Play

Answer (score 3):

Same steps 1-2 as frants' answer, however you don't need to restart the game and use the console.

Just choose *Play* -> *Offline with bots* -> *Workshop*. Select the map and press **Play**.

Comment: Yea, but for the future is easier to type in to console map aim_botz and u can play ;)

Comment: Copy and paste the link @frants used into a web page in your steam overlay. Then do steps 4 and 5.